# Identification of Latent Variables in Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: bayesian, identifiability, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am building an Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) model which estimates a version of the Author-Topic model developed by Rosen-Zvi, Griffiths, Steyvers and Smyth. The original paper is [here](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1207.4169).

The author-topic model estimates a distribution across a set of K topics for each of the n authors in a given dataset, as well as the traditional distribution across W words for each of the K topics. The estimation is a probabilistic Bayesian method, in my case estimating an MCMC process using Gibbs Sampling.

I want to know how to discuss and evaluate how well identified each author distribution is. For example, the distribution for a given author across topics is better identified for authors who produce a lot of documents, in a lot of different teams of authors and whose co-authors are also well identified themselves.

At the moment I am stuck at an intuitive understanding that some of the latent variables in LDA models are better identified than others; can anyone recommend methods &/or literature for formalising these arguments?